# TomTom TrafficFlow API different OpenLR data using Protobuf and Datex2 (XML)

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, tomtom

We are planning to change our Java app from using [TomTom Traffic Flow - Intermediate Service - DatexII](https://developer.tomtom.com/intermediate-traffic-service/intermediate-traffic-service/tomtom-traffic-flow-intermediate-service-datexii) to [TomTom Traffic Flow - Intermediate Service - Protobuf](https://developer.tomtom.com/intermediate-traffic-service/intermediate-traffic-service/tomtom-traffic-flow-intermediate-service-protobuf), but we are facing a problem with OpenLR data.

In datexII, the response comes in a XML. The binary for OpenLR is a normal String like this: `CwcZ6yJrqQslDgRLAQULFw==`

But when we use the Protobuff option, we have a location object that contains:

`openlr: "\v\377\276\372\036:a#\213\v\000\361\376\225$\r"`.

It has a `.getOpenLR()` method that returns a ByteString object like this (toString):

`16 bytes [0x0b,0xff,0xbe,0xfa,0x1e,0x3a,0x61,0x23,0x8b,0x0b,0x00,0xf1,0xfe,0x95,0x24,0x0d]`

We've tried everything, but we cannot get the same String from the XML or any format OpenLR can decode from there. As OpenLR is developed by TomTom and they recommend to use Protobuf to get data, there must be a way to get OpenLR locations from that ByteString. Any ideas?

PS: there is also another difference, the XML has an ID for each Object, which Protobuf doesn't.

PS2: there is no OpenLR tag :S